# Can't get AngularJS routing to work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, wampserver

I am sure there is something simple that I am missing but I can't seem to find it. I have a super simple Angular JS SPA. The folder structure is as follows:

index.php
-- js
    -- app.js
-- pages
    -- home.html
    -- post.html
    -- know.html

in index.php I have:

```
<html class="no-js" lang="en" ng-app="postApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Post Safety App</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <base href="/postsafetyapp/">
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="mainController">
        <main id="main">
            <div ng-view></div>
        </main>

        <!-- Angular JS -->
        <script src="js/vendor/angular.min.js"></script>  
        <script src="js/vendor/angular-route.min.js"></script>        

        <!-- Custom JS -->
        <script src="js/app.js"></script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

in home.html I have:

```
<div class="home buttons">
    <div class="button button-1-of-2">
        <a href="#share" class="button__link" id="button_share">
            <span class="button__icon"><i class="fa fa-share"></i></span>
            <span class="button__text">SHARE</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="button button-1-of-2">
        <a href="#know" class="button__link" id="button_share">
            <span class="button__icon"><i class="fa fa-graduation-cap"></i></span>
            <span class="button__text">KNOW</span>
        </a>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Here is the code in the app.js:

```
// create the main module
var postApp = angular.module("postApp", ['ngRoute']);

// configure our routes
postApp.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider

         // route for the home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
            controller  : 'mainController'
        })

        // route for the know page
        .when('/know', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/know.html',
            controller  : 'knowController'
        })

        // route for the share page
        .when('/share', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/share.html',
            controller  : 'shareController'
        });

        // use the HTML5 History API
        // $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        //      enabled: true,
        //      requireBase: false
        //  });

    });
```

The home.html page loads just fine, the URL appears as follows:

http://localhost/postsafetyapp/#!/

If I click on the share button, the URL changes to:

http://localhost/postsafetyapp/#!/#share

But the view doesn't change.

If I un-comment the $locationProvider code the URLs become:

http://localhost/postsafetyapp/    (home.html page loads no problem)

click on the button and the URL becomes:

http://localhost/postsafetyapp/#share     (View doesn't change)

I am running WAMPSERVER on my local server.
Any help would be amazing!

Comment: i cannot see ui-view directive ,the place where routes html should be loaded, where it located?

Comment: can you add these codes in JSFiddle or Plunker to see what you have done exactly?

Comment: happyZZR1400 - this code is not using UI router, but using angularjs's default ng router. instead of ui-view, need to use ng-view.

Comment: Ah yeah, good idea, let me see what I can do in JSFiddle

I am just using angular-route.min.js local file

I will update the ticket to show the ng-view in index.html

Comment: if you using default angular router - you must have ng-view somewhere, on index or home views

Comment: It should be in main html file, where angularjs ng app is used, like index.html

Comment: Thanks for your help on this! I have added in what I have in my index.php file to the ticket.

Comment: Ok, so I changed the links of the anchors in index.php to be just "share" and "know" instead of the "#share" and now it seems to be working. I can't refresh the page though so I am not sure if that is standard or not? i.e. 

If I go to localhost/postsafetyapp then click on the share button the url becomes localhost/postsafetyapp/share but if I hit refresh it says that postsafetyapp/share is not found. Is that the way it is suppose to work?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the controller in app config

Please compare the code with the plnkr link

[**Click here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/oDFG8nTWVfvZj3cz33c6?p=preview) for working code in plnkr.

If you want to see the url to see how page gets routed use the below link

[**Seperate plnkr window** (without code)](https://run.plnkr.co/zE77wQSbGkgim5nH/#!/about)

href in index page

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#!/home"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!/about"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!/contact"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
```

Controller defined in app config:

```
// create the module and name it scotchApp
var scotchApp = angular.module('scotchApp', ['ngRoute']);

// configure our routes
scotchApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider

  // route for the home page
    .when('/home', {
    templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
    controller: 'mainController'
  })

  // route for the about page
  .when('/about', {
    templateUrl: 'pages/about.html',
    controller: 'aboutController'
  })

  // route for the contact page
  .when('/contact', {
    templateUrl: 'pages/contact.html',
    controller: 'contactController'
  })

  //otherwise redirect to home
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: "/home"
  });
});

// create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
scotchApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
  // create a message to display in our view
  $scope.message = 'Everyone come and see how good I look!!!!';
});

scotchApp.controller('aboutController', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = 'Look! I am an about page.';
});

scotchApp.controller('contactController', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = 'Contact us!.';
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, this all seems to work good, however I tried adding the $locationProvider to your Plunkr example with no luck. I can get it to work with the hash in the url but can't seem to get it to work without.